# URLLoader is not working in flex 4.6 Mobile Project for Android

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, picasa

URLLoader is not dispatching Event.COMPLETE event on Android Mobile, although it is working properly in Flash Builder Mobile Debugging. The code snippet is given below:

```
private function loadAlbumData():void
{
 var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default");
    var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
  urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
  urlloader.load(request); 

}

private function onLoadComplete(evt:Event):void
{

   trace(evt.currentTarget.data);
}
```

Here I am requesting an Album XML from Google's Picasa service.

Comment: Listen for error events and see what they tell you: `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR`, `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS`, `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR`

Comment: @RIAstar u r right. It throws IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR. The trace shows 


"[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default" errorID=2032]"

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of that XML page, it is pulling in data relevant to me. Best guess is it relies on being signed into Google to determine who the user is. If the user doesn't have a Google cookie (tested by signing out of Google), it returns "Authorization Required", which might be returned as HTTP status error rather than an actual page. Because apps are sandboxed, cookies are not shared between apps or even the system without explicitly asking for them to be (which would likely require an ANE)

In this case, you have two options:

1. Figure out how to allow the user to sign into Google, save the cookie, and send it in the request. I have never dealt with cookies in Flash so I would not be able to help you here
2. Use `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/USERNAMEHERE` where USERNAMEHERE is the username of the account you want to pull data from.

Obviously the solution depends on the implementation of this feature, so I won't recommend which one to use. But that is definitely your issue here.

Comment: 1. I am able to sign into Google and able to get Authorization Token, but using that token I am unable to get that users Album XML which would be required to get the albumid to fetch photos from that particular Album. So as you see 'signing in' is not the problem here.

2. `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/USERNAMEHERE` the problem with this is that, using this link I can fetch only public albums and not private albums.